# Problem with displaying characters in React Native App

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-native

I have a weird problem, I connect my WordPress website with React Native App using API Key. When I add some products from my WordPress website with title example: **Soccer Ball & Tennis Ball** on WordPress website I see normal title the same as I write above but when I open my React Native App I get this title **Soccer Ball &#03 8 ; Tennis Ball**. But when I look at the text I write in React Native App example **€** it's displayed as I write. Where is problem, is problem Fonts or something else?

Thanks all for your help

Comment: Stackoverflow register **&#03 8 ;** as a **&**.

Comment: what the result when using other symbols same unicode?

Comment: I didn't try I have only **&** symbol entered with the result of **&#03 8 ;* @UA_